# How to Connect a printer to React Native Android App via USB Connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, printing

Trying to connect a thermal printer to React Native via USB Connection. I tried many packages from Github, none of them works so far. How can we connect the printer via USB connection to React Native Android Application and print? Is there any Serial connection method to do this?

Comment: can you provide more information on the type and model of your thermal printer? That makes it easier for others to point you in the right diretion

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important parts of figuring out whether this is possible is to determine whether your termal printer has an iOS or Android SDK. If that's possible, then you can create a custom react-native module to make it accessible in your JavaScript code.

Check the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) on how to do this for iOS for example.

Comment: I don't know the model number or any other info. It does have Bluetooth and it works. The only USB connection is not working.

Comment: One way or another, you are going to need model and brand information. A thermal printer often has a way it expects the input to be sent.